# What's another way of writing this block without using do-end?

Tags: ruby

How would you write this on the same line or on consecutive lines without do-end?

```
map.resources :magazines do |magazine| magazine.resources :ads end
```

Comment: map.resources :magazines { |magazine| magazine.resources :ads }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wouldn't using curly braces work?

```
map.resources :magazines {|magazine| magazine.resources :ads}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `do`/`end`, you could simply use `{`/`}`:

```
map.resources :magazines {|magazine| magazine.resources :ads}
```

Comment: Yes, as long as the opening brace is on the same line as the method call.